# The MAC address value isn't recognized by other node messages

Tags: omnet++, veins

I'm using `Veins 5.0`. Here is the code I've written:

**NodeMsg.msg**

```
cplusplus{{
    #import "veins/base/utils/Coord.h"
    #import "veins/modules/utility/Consts80211p.h"
    #include "veins/modules/messages/BaseFrame1609_4_m.h"
    #include "veins/base/utils/SimpleAddress.h"
}};

namespace veins;

class noncobject Coord;
class BaseFrame1609_4;
class noncobject LAddress::L2Type;

packet mR_SA extends BaseFrame1609_4
{
    int isWlan; // IEEE 80211p and LTE classification variables
    int mrsuId;
    int type;
    int status;
    int remainingCapacity;
    int neighborVehiclesCount;
    int checksum; 
    double direction;
    double velocity;
    double posX; // longitude
    double posY; // latitude
    simtime_t timestamp = 0;
    LAddress::L2Type macId; // MAC address
}
```

**Node.h**

```
#include "veins/modules/mac/ieee80211p/DemoBaseApplLayerToMac1609_4Interface.h"
...

class VEINS_API Node : public DemoBaseApplLayer
{
     ...
     public:
         LAddress::L2Type nodeMacId = 0;
}
```

**Node.cc**

```
...
else if(stage == 1)
{
     mac = FindModule<DemoBaseApplLayerToMac1609_4Interface*>::findSubModule(getParentModule());
     ASSERT(mac);

     nodeMacId = mac -> getMACAddress();
}

...

void Node::handleSelfMsg(cMessage* msg)
{
     ... 
     mR_SA* mr_sa = new mR_SA();
     ...
     mr_sa -> setMacId(nodeMacId);

     BaseFrame1609_4* wsm = new BaseFrame1609_4();
     wsm -> encapsulate(mr_sa);
     populateWSM(wsm);
     sendDelayedDown(wsm, uniform(0.01, 0.50));
}
```

**AnotherNode.cc**

```
...
mR_SA* mr_sa = new mR_SA();
LAddress::L2Type nodeMacId = mr_sa -> getMacId();

EV_TRACE << "MAC address: " << nodeMacId << std::endl;
...
```

The log is displayed as the `MAC` address value obtained from `Node` is `326`. However, the `MAC` address value received from the message by another node is `0`. Why does this happen?

There are no errors at all when running the current code in simulation form after building. I suspected that a different type was the cause, so I did a cast to a `long` type, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AnotherNode.cc` is creating a fresh `mR_SA` using `new`, but is expecting to find the sending node's mac address in there. This will not work. Rather, you would need to cast the received `cMessage` to this type and use member accessors to get the mac address.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Knowing that the `new` keyword creates a new object, it was structurally misunderstood. I was able to fix it using `check_and_cast<>()`.